# Question related to symbolic links and copying

Tags: symlink

So the following command copies from `/source/allsubdirectroies` (`/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235`) to a `/target` (`/tmp/jar263`) folder:

```
find /usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235 -type f -name "*.jar" -exec cp {} /tmp/jar263 \;
```

The problem for me is that in the source directory there are files with symbolic link, i.e.:
    hadoop-nfs.jar -> hadoop-nfs-2.7.3.2.6.3.0-235.jar

So when I check my `/tmp/jar263` folder I see the following file:

```
hadoop-nfs-2.7.3.2.6.3.0-235.jar
```

However what I want is the "hadoop-nfs.jar" name.

Any way to get the link name not the original name of the file?

There are many links in the `usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/` folder/subfolder structure.

Comment: `man find` and check the options for `-type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man find`, ubuntu manpages version:

> -L     Follow symbolic links.  When find examines or prints information about files, the information used
>          shall be taken from the properties of the file to which the link points, not from the link  itself
>          (unless  it  is  a  broken  symbolic  link or find is unable to examine the file to which the link
>          points).  Use of this option implies -noleaf.  If you later use the -P option, -noleaf will  still
>          be  in effect.  If -L is in effect and find discovers a symbolic link to a subdirectory during its
>          search, the subdirectory pointed to by the symbolic link will be searched.
>
> When the -L option is in effect, the -type predicate will always match against  the  type  of  the
>          file  that  a  symbolic  link  points  to rather than the link itself (unless the symbolic link is
>          broken).  Using -L causes the -lname and -ilname predicates always to return false.

So `find -L /usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235 -type f -name "*.jar" -exec cp {} /tmp/jar263 \;` should do the trick. Make sure to read the options under **-type**, as roaima suggested, if you run into any strange behavior (find may behave slightly differently on, e.g. OSX).

Comment: There's also the possibility of using `-L` with `cp` instead of with `find`, depending on what name one wants to have at the target.